# Get id of div in parent document

Tags: html, facebook, iframe, fbml

I need to get the id of a `div` in the parent document of an iframed document. The actual scenario is I have a facebook application developed using FBML. The canvas page contains an `iframe`. If the user clicks on a button inside the iframed document, I need to display a div in the canvas page that is hidden when loading.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

did you try `parent.document.getElementById('YOUR_ID');` ?

Comment: +1, I hope you don't mind the edit, but I formatted the inline-code as code =) It's worth taking a read of the [Stackoverflow Markdown help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to get a feel for things.

Comment: Oops, Damodaran, I understood your question wrong. So, what div you need know id of? Anyway, you can access parent document by `parent.document.` var.

Answer (score 1):

Are both documents (parent and iframe) in the same domain? If no, then browser doesn't allow you to access to parent document for security reasons.

EDIT: If both documents are in the same domain then you can access the element of parent document as follows:

```
var parentDoc = parent.document;
var el = parentDoc.getElementById("foobar");
```

Comment: So, you can get the element of parent document using code I've just added to my answer. Or using an appropriate jQuery expression.

Answer (score 0):

try `$(this).parent().attr('id')`